# Teradata Studio - Load data with

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to load data into Teradata using Teradata Studio. Using FastLoad (Load Data Wizard) from Delimited Text.

It keeps crashing on Decimal symbol which is "," in my file. This is standard in my country. And no matter what setting I use - Check/Uncheck "Use system Locale" it crashes on this.
The local settings on my PC shows "," as Decimal separator.

I am sure this is the issue. It worked when I manually removed decimals from the file.

Any advice besides modifying the file or changing the column type into VarChar?

Thanks, R.

Comment: What does "keeps crashing" mean? Checking "Use system Locale" works fine for me. Maybe try upgrading to the latest Studio version?